# Deploy app to service fabric with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-service-fabric

I have service fabric up and running in Azure. Also I have Visual Studio solution with two projects: Service Fabric and Web Service. 
I would like to deploy the service to the service fabric in azure.
When I right-click my service fabric project and click "Publish", the service smoothly deploys to the cloud fabric. I would like to do the same with PowerShell.

It seems I need to run this script:

```
# Connect to the cluster using a client certificate.
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint $endpoint `
      -KeepAliveIntervalInSec 10 `
      -X509Credential -ServerCertThumbprint $thumbprint `
      -FindType FindByThumbprint -FindValue $thumbprint `
      -StoreLocation CurrentUser -StoreName My

# Copy the application package to the cluster image store.
Copy-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage $packagepath -ImageStoreConnectionString fabric:ImageStore -ApplicationPackagePathInImageStore $packagename

# Register the application type.
Register-ServiceFabricApplicationType -ApplicationPathInImageStore $packagename

# Create the service instance.
$appName = <name that I see in fabric explorer under 'typeName' in azure>
New-ServiceFabricService -ApplicationName fabric:/$appName -ServiceName fabric:/$appName/MyApp -ServiceTypeName $serviceTypeName -Stateless -PartitionSchemeSingleton -InstanceCount -1
```

Prior to running the script I right click my fabric app and select "Package".

The very last command of my script fails with "application not found"

What can be missing?

Comment: Did you first build a package using `msbuild HelloWorld.sfproj /t:Package` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I used wrong `ApplicationName` and `ServiceName` in the command `New-ServiceFabricService`.

In order to find out what correct values are, I ran `Get-ServiceFabricApplication` and `Get-ServiceFabricService`.

These pages were very helpful for building troubleshooting the scripts:

- [Deploy and remove applications using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-remove-applications)
- [Service Fabric application upgrade using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-upgrade-tutorial-powershell)

Answer (score 4):

Once you have the package build and ready, you can try the below commands in order to deploy the pkg using PowerShell Script.

If you haven't tried the below option, try this and see if it works.

There are few prerequisites that's needed in order to run the script :

- You have your cluster up and running.
- Cluster has all necessary certificates deployed (such as for SSL
  endpoints, if any)
- You have ARM template and parameters files ready.
- You have the necessary permissions for deployment of new resources,
  namely the Contributor role (on the level of subscription or resource
  group)
- You have the destination resource group created

Once you check the above, execute the following commands:

Copy-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage

Register-ServiceFabricApplicationType

New-ServiceFabricApplication

If that doesn't work for you, go through the below sites to see if it helps .

[Deploy applications using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-remove-applications)

[Deploy resources with Resource Manager templates and Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-deploy)